# How can i reduce to a more concise form my JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

There is the following piece of code that I would like to reduce to a more concise form. I think I did not make the best decision at all.
Simultaneously getting rid of the bug, which consists in limiting the operation of the program from arrays prescribed in advance in the code. Please tell me how it can be done. Jquery library 3.5.1

```
function FaendKey(arr){
    var Key = [];
    for (zz = 0; zz < arr.length; zz++) {
        if (fileSystem[zz].name == arr[0]) {
            Key.push(zz);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (arr.length > 2) {
        var arrKeyOld = fileSystem[Key[0]].items;
        for (z = 1; z < arr.length-1; z++) {
            var tickKey = FaendKeyOld(arr[z],arrKeyOld);
            Key.push(tickKey);
            arrKeyOld = arrKeyOld[tickKey].items;
        }
    }
    return Key;
}
function onSuccess(data){
    for (k = 0; k < data.d.results.length; k++) {
        var UrlFull = data.d.results[k].ServerRelativeUrl.split('/');
        UrlFull.splice(0,4);
        var idKey = [];
        var idKey = FaendKey(UrlFull);
        if (idKey.length == 1) {
            fileSystem[idKey[0]].items.push(
                {
                    name: data.d.results[k].Name,
                    isDirectory: true, __KEY__: data.d.results[k].UniqueId,
                    dateModified: data.d.results[k].TimeLastModified,
                    items: [],
                }
            )
        } else {
            if (idKey.length == 2) {
                fileSystem[idKey[0]].items[idKey[1]].items.push(
                    {
                        name: data.d.results[k].Name,
                        isDirectory: true, __KEY__: data.d.results[k].UniqueId,
                        dateModified: data.d.results[k].TimeLastModified,
                        items: [],
                    }
                )
            }
            if (idKey.length == 3) {
                fileSystem[idKey[0]].items[idKey[1]].items[idKey[2]].items.push(
                    {
                        name: data.d.results[k].Name,
                        isDirectory: true, __KEY__: data.d.results[k].UniqueId,
                        dateModified: data.d.results[k].TimeLastModified,
                        items: [],
                    }
                )
            }
.. and then a similar structure up to the value idKey.length == 10...
```

Comment: @zer00ne Considering this program contains known bugs they want to get fixed, it's not suitable for CR at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a recursive function for that

something like this

```
const saveItem = (keys, data, store) => {
 if(keys.length === 1){
   store.items.push(data)
   return;
  }
  const [key, ...rest] = keys
  return saveItem(rest, data, store[key])
}
```

than you can call it like this

```
function onSuccess(data){
    for (k = 0; k < data.d.results.length; k++) {
        var UrlFull = data.d.results[k].ServerRelativeUrl.split('/');
        UrlFull.splice(0,4);
        var idKey = [];
        var idKey = FaendKey(UrlFull);
        const data =  {
                    name: data.d.results[k].Name,
                    isDirectory: true, __KEY__: data.d.results[k].UniqueId,
                    dateModified: data.d.results[k].TimeLastModified,
                    items: [],
                }
       saveItem(idKey, data, fileSystem) 
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you explain what the means string `const [key, ...rest] = keys` ?

Comment: @Flaxin it just separate the first element of the array from the rest

Answer (score 0):

A use case for `filter`:

```js
    var Key = [];
    for (zz = 0; zz < arr.length; zz++) {
        if (fileSystem[zz].name == arr[0]) {
            Key.push(zz);
            break;
        }
```

try:

```js
var Key = arr.filter(x => fileSystem[x].name == arr[0])
```